# How to synchronize multiple goroutines on one critical section?

Tags: go

I need to synchronize a number of goroutines `1..n` that run code in an interpreted language (written in Go) on a critical section of interpreted code running in a goroutine `k`, which may be any of `1..n` at runtime. I.e., if the code in `k` is running in the critical section, all other goroutines `i (i≠k; 1≤k,i≤n)` need to be suspended until `k` is finished. The solution also needs to deal with erroneous nesting of critical sections, either by processing at the outermost level or by signalling an error.

The problem is that each of these goroutines may run code in a tight loop and I have no direct control over this code - it's interpreted, supplied by the user. Things I've considered:

1. Mess with the interpreter to include some kind of yield or checks. This seems like a very inefficient way of dealing with it. The language allows for recursion, so I'd have to check every function call.
2. Suspend goroutines `i` while they are running, from `k` in a non-cooperative way? Is it possible to suspend a goroutine in Go "from the outside (`=k`)"?
3. Supply a way in the target language to co-operatively check whether `k` is running and halt if needed. I'm reluctant to do this, since it basically is a leaky abstraction for channels. It would also make programming very complicated and I want my interpreted language to remain simple.

What would you recommend. Is Option 2 even possible? Is there another way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't suspend or kill a goroutine from the "outside". The goroutine has to show cooperation for such requests.

Comment: That's a huge bummer, so Option 2 is out. The problem with Option 1 is that I'd have to include checks for every loop and recursion. E.g. if I iterate over an array in Go, I'd have to check during the loop if k is running. That sounds insanely expensive.

Comment: "I want my interpreted language to remain simple" - you're going to have to make some sacrifices if you want it to support concurrency and synchronization.